# Coalesce columns and create another column to specify source

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr::coalesce()` to combine several columns into one. Originally, across columns, each row has only one column with actual value while the other columns are `NA`. Based on the coalescing, I want to create an additional column that will specify the *source* column from which the coalesced value was taken from.

My attempt is inspired by existing functionality in other `dplyr` functions. For example, `dplyr::bind_rows()` has `.id` argument that specifies the source dataframe for each row in the new dataframe.

From `bind_rows()`'s documentation:

> When .id is supplied, a new column of identifiers is created to link
> each row to its original data frame. The labels are taken from the
> named arguments to bind_rows(). When a list of data frames is
> supplied, the labels are taken from the names of the list. If no names
> are found a numeric sequence is used instead.

Again, my current question is about `coalesce()`, not `bind_rows()`, but I just wanted to put it in context.

### Data

```r
df <-
  data.frame(
  group_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2),
  group_2 = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, NA),
  group_3 = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA),
  group_4 = c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA),
  group_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

df

##   group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5         ## each row
## 1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA         ## has one value
## 2      NA       4      NA      NA      NA         ## and the rest
## 3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA         ## are NAs
## 4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA
## 5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

### Combining the columns into one (additional) column

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(one_col = coalesce(group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4, group_5))

##   group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col
## 1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA       1
## 2      NA       4      NA      NA      NA       4
## 3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA       5
## 4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA       2
## 5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA       2
```

**How can I add yet another column that will specify the "source", i.e., from which column the value in `one_col` was taken from?**

#### Desired output

```r
  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col source_col
1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA       1    group_4
2      NA       4      NA      NA      NA       4    group_2
3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA       5    group_3
4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA       2    group_4
5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    group_1
```

---

EDIT

---

@Karthik's answer below led me thinking that the example data I used above demonstrates a situation that is too narrow and specific. The solution Karthik offers is independent of the coalescing operation. Thus, the code would still work if we swap the order and create the `source_col` first and only then `coalesce`.

However, if the data had more than one `NA` per row, `coalesce` would still do its thing, but we could no longer base `source_col` on finding the single non-missing value. Therefore, I'm revising the question and the data.

### Data

```r
df_2 <-
  data.frame(
  group_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2),
  group_2 = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, 1),
  group_3 = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA),
  group_4 = c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA),
  group_5 = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA)
)

> df_2

##   group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5
## 1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA   ## <--- one non-NA
## 2      NA       4      NA      NA       3   ## <--- *two* non-NA
## 3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA   ## <--- one non-NA
## 4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA   ## <--- one non-NA
## 5       2       1      NA      NA      NA   ## <--- *two* non-NA
```

### Coalescing

```r
> df_2 %>%
   mutate(one_col = coalesce(group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4, group_5))

##   group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col
## 1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA       1
## 2      NA       4      NA      NA       3       4
## 3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA       5
## 4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA       2
## 5       2       1      NA      NA      NA       2
```

**How can I add a source column that will *match* the value chosen by `coalesce()` with the original column it came from?**

***Desired Output***

```r
  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col source_col
1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA       1    group_4
2      NA       4      NA      NA       3       4    group_2
3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA       5    group_3
4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA       2    group_4
5       2       1      NA      NA      NA       2    group_1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df %>%
   mutate(one_col = coalesce(group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4, group_5)) %>% 
rowwise() %>% mutate(group_col = names(df)[!is.na(c_across(group_1:group_5))])
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col group_col
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl> <chr>    
1      NA      NA      NA       1 NA            1 group_4  
2      NA       4      NA      NA NA            4 group_2  
3      NA      NA       5      NA NA            5 group_3  
4      NA      NA      NA       2 NA            2 group_4  
5       2      NA      NA      NA NA            2 group_1  
>
```

Updated Answer:

```
df_2 %>% mutate(one_col = coalesce(group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4, group_5)) %>% rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(group_col = names(df_2)[!is.na(c_across(group_1:group_5))][1])
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 one_col group_col
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA       1 group_4  
2      NA       4      NA      NA       3       4 group_2  
3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA       5 group_3  
4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA       2 group_4  
5       2       1      NA      NA      NA       2 group_1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Karthik. Your solution gets the work done given the data I put. However, it's not what I had in my mind when publishing the question. I've edited the post to clarify this.

Comment: I like this solution, @KarthikS, but it doesn't quite work when I try to apply it in a more general case.  If you keep that example dataframe *exactly* the same, my use case is analogous to doing the `coalesce()` on `group_2, group_3, group_5` only.  I am not sure how to do the select inside `c_across()`, plus I'll get `group_1` as an answer for row 5.  This is so close to what I need though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick *base* solution:

```
cbind(df_2,
      t(apply(df_2, 1, function(i){
        c(i[ which(!is.na(i))[1] ],
          colnames(df_2)[ which(!is.na(i))[1] ])
      }))
      )
#   group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 1       2
# 1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA 1 group_4
# 2      NA       4      NA      NA       3 4 group_2
# 3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA 5 group_3
# 4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA 2 group_4
# 5       2       1      NA      NA      NA 2 group_1
```

Pretty sure, this can be done using "which.min/is.na/arrayInd" combo without *apply* loops, no time at the moment to test.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be reshaping the data from wide format to long format.

```
df2 <- reshape(df,
               direction = 'long',
               varying = 1:5,
               v.names = 'one_col',
               timevar = 'source_col',
               times = paste0('group_', 1:5))
```

Either of these functions will drop the `NA` columns returned by `reshape`

```
df2[!is.na(df2$one_col), ]
na.omit(df2)

          source_col one_col id
5.group_1    group_1       2  5
2.group_2    group_2       4  2
3.group_3    group_3       5  3
1.group_4    group_4       1  1
4.group_4    group_4       2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the transpose of the dataframe, then the rownames of the `which( . , arr.in)` turn out to be exactly the right result.

```
cbind( df, group_col = rownames( which(!is.na(t(df)), arr.ind=TRUE)) )
  group_1 group_2 group_3 group_4 group_5 group_col
1      NA      NA      NA       1      NA   group_4
2      NA       4      NA      NA      NA   group_2
3      NA      NA       5      NA      NA   group_3
4      NA      NA      NA       2      NA   group_4
5       2      NA      NA      NA      NA   group_1
```